# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto (que não é nulo)

Tags: c#

Estou tentando mostrar a quantidade de espaço livre de um drive (o C:) mas recebo o erro "Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto".

Quando utilizo uma `MessageBox` para mostrar o espaço livre ele retorna em bytes o valor sem problemas, mas ao tentar atribuir o valor a uma `Label` recebo o erro. O código é o seguinte:

```
private void SetMainPage()
{
    DriveInfo C = new DriveInfo("C");
    espacoHD.Text = C.TotalFreeSpace.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Esse erro claramente indica que é nulo. O seu teste deve estar diferente disto.

Comment: Então por que MessageBox.Show(C.TotalFreeSpace) consegue retornar o valor?

Comment: Ou o erro não é aí ou está diferente, não tem outra forma.

Comment: Se o MessageBox dá certo, é porquê `espacoHD` é nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o espacoHD é que está nulo. Segue código que fiz e funcionou.

```
DriveInfo C = new DriveInfo("C");

Label espacoHD = new Label();
espacoHD.Text = C.TotalFreeSpace.ToString();
```

Comment: Agora não recebo a exception, mas a Label fica invisível como se não tivesse valor.

Comment: Entendi, o que deve estar acontecendo é que o nome da sua label não é exatamente igual ao que está no código. O C# é sensível a letras maiúsculas e minusculas. Caso o nome não esteja igual mesmo, pode retirar a linha `Label espacoHD = new Label();` . Para não errar no nome da label. utilize `this.nomedalabel.Text`